# Java...While Loop Program

Tags: java, while-loop

I've got a homework assignment...code is below...got several questions about it...thanks in advance. Beginner Java student...if this looks cludgey, please don't laugh >.>
Code below...

```
    /*
     * Getting to know you...
     * @author Elle dela Victoria
     * @version 092812
     */
       import java.util.*;
       public class A15_1
       {
           public static void main(String[] args)
           {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.print(
           "Mind answering some questions for me?\n" +
           "Type quit when you're ready to leave.\n");

       while(true)
       {
        System.out.print("Does your name start with the letter H? ");
        input.nextLine();
        int ans = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
        if (ans == 0)
            System.out.println("That's awesome!");
        if (ans == 1)
            System.out.println("Awww, how unfortunate!");
        if (ans == 2)
            System.out.println("You're amazing at this!");
        if (ans == 3)
            System.out.println("LOL!");
        if (ans == 4)
            System.out.println("WTF!! That's horrible!");

        System.out.print("Are you male? ");
        input.nextLine();
        int ans1 = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
        if (ans1 == 0)
            System.out.println("That's awesome!");
        if (ans1 == 1)
            System.out.println("Awww, how unfortunate!");
        if (ans1 == 2)
            System.out.println("You're amazing at this!");
        if (ans1 == 3)
            System.out.println("LOL!");
        if (ans1 == 4)
            System.out.println("WTF!! That's horrible!");

        System.out.print("Are you female?");
        input.nextLine();
        int ans2 = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
        if (ans2 == 0)
            System.out.println("That's awesome!");
        if (ans2 == 1)
            System.out.println("Awww, how unfortunate!");
        if (ans2 == 2)
            System.out.println("You're amazing at this!");
        if (ans2 == 3)
            System.out.println("LOL!");
        if (ans2 == 4)
            System.out.println("WTF!! That's horrible!");

        System.out.print("Are you in school right now?");
        input.nextLine();
        int ans3 = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
        if (ans3 == 0)
            System.out.println("So angry when you're sober!");
        if (ans3 == 1)
            System.out.println("Awww, how unfortunate!");
        if (ans3 == 2)
            System.out.println("You're amazing at this!");
        if (ans3 == 3)
            System.out.println("LOL!");
        if (ans3 == 4)
            System.out.println("WTF!! That's horrible!");

        String userinput = input.nextLine();
        if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
            break;      
      }
   }
 }
```

1. is there any way to use my IF statements for every question I ask without having to change the String name for each question?
2. is there any way to create a method (?) for those if statements, so I don't have to write them out for EVERY question I ask?
3. If the user doesn't input an answer in 10 seconds, I'd like to have a timer that prompts them for an answer, how do I do this?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - Keep up the good work! ;)

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I tend to do it every time I can.

Comment: Short answers: 1) no, 2) yes, but the method will include all your `if`s statements and the `String`s in it. 3) It is possible but you're saying that you're a beginner, so it would be better to not look for this feature in console applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of strings and print them according to the input `ans`:

```
    String str[] = {"That's awesome!", "Awww, how unfortunate!",
     "You're amazing at this!", "LOL!", "WTF!! That's horrible!"};

      /* code */

  while(true)
       {
        System.out.print("Does your name start with the letter H? ");
        input.nextLine();
        int ans = (int)(Math.random() * str.length);
        System.out.println(str[ans]);

      /* code */
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can. You create a method with a parameter of type `int` to use:

   ```
   public void printReply(int ans) {
       if (ans == 0)
           System.out.println("So angry when you're sober!");
       if (ans == 1)
           System.out.println("Awww, how unfortunate!");
       if (ans == 2)
           System.out.println("You're amazing at this!");
       if (ans == 3)
           System.out.println("LOL!");
       if (ans == 4)
           System.out.println("WTF!! That's horrible!");
   }
   ```

   Call this where appropriate.
2. Not sure I understand, I think the first answer covers this.
3. Look into the [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) method, which is specified by all `Object`s.

As an aside, you're not doing anything with your input.  You let it drop on the floor by calling `input.nextLine()`.  You should look into capturing that in a variable.

Comment: For #3, that's not going to do what you think it will do. `input.nextLine()` is a blocking call, as-is `wait`. He would want a timer for this, which will require some other code to go alongside it. You should also change the `if`s to a switch statement, or at least `if-else if-else if` (I realize it was copy-pasted).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this answers 1, but it should answer 2:

```
private String getAnswer() {
   int ans = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
   switch(ans) {
   case 0:
      return "That's awesome!";
   case 1:
      return "Awww, how unfortunate!";
   [... and so on ...]
   }
   return null
}
```

Than just call it where you need an answer like this: `System.out.println(getAnswer());`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a list to store the responses. This will alleviate the need for `if` statements and also prevents you from having to add a new response in four different places.

```
List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();
responseList.add("That's awesome!");
responseList.add("LOL!");
responseList.add(.....);

System.out.println(responseList.get(ans));
```